# .on("change" not working on partialView

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, onchange

I'm using a

```
$(".titleField").on("change", function () {
                // change title
                alert("hello");
            });
```

On a field that I've loaded with ajax call:

```
<input class="form-control autosize titleField text-box single-line valid" type="text" value="">
```

But I have no alert that are shown and no error in the console, why? How can i bind the on change on this item loaded in a partial webpage?

When I put the selector in console, it shows me right input...

Thanks in advance

Comment: try event delegation - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements

Answer (score 2):

You need to event delegation with dynamic added element. Check **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/usoxscow/1/)**

```
$(document).on("change keyup",".titleField", function () {
   // change title
    alert("hello");
});
```

Check [Event Delegation Manual](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Comment: And see the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/k7bspj4f/ for the behaviour of the change event (it will not fire for each keypress, so no typeahead. Use "keyup" or similar for typeahead stuff).